# action delegate. How to get methods infos called in delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates

I need to get MethodInfo for method called in Action delegate in order to check, whether methods called in Action has MyCustomAttibute

```
    public void Foo( Action action )
    {
        if(Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(action.Method, typeof(MyCustomAttribute)).Count() == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid action");
        }
    }
```

The Foo method should be able to be called as following:

```
    Foo(() =>
    {
            instanceOfFooClass.Method1().Method2();
    });
```

In Foo method I want to be sure that Method1 and Method2 has MyCustomAttribute. However action.Method is giving me the MethodInfo, which is the action of delegate, which happens when using lambda expression. Is there any way to get Method1 and Method2 MethodInfo?

Comment: Excellent question. Not very easily, AFAIK. You could *probably* do it easily enough with an `Expression<Action>`, but then you can't *directly* execute it

Comment: I agree you will have to use expression trees for that. I don't know how much it will hurt performance.

Comment: If not directly, then how could you execute it?

Comment: By using [Expression.Compile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362.aspx).

Comment: The other problem is that lambda expression with a statement body cannot be used as Expression<Action>.

Comment: @user1439510 indeed, the C# compiler won't do that - although in .NET 4.0 the *expression* API technically supports that scenario - the compiler doesn't. It is moot, though, because it is much harder to parse such a complex model.

Comment: This wont ever work; you cannot decorate a closure/anonymous method with an attribute.

Comment: As a more general approach: is there any library out there, which converts a MethodInfo or anything like that to expression trees? If he needs a generic solution for all cases, its not far from that (and that might be something very hard to do)

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, `Expression<T>` is probably the best way to achieve this.  However, it requires a `Compile()` at runtime so it should be performance profiled.

With `Expression<T>` you can easily get access to Method info like this:

```
public MethodInfo GetMethodInfo(Expression<Action> action)
{
    return ((MethodCallExpression)action.Body).Method;
}
```

But, before executing the action you must do this:

```
private void InvokeMethod(Expression<Action> action)
{
    action.Compile().Invoke();
}
```

**EDIT**
Ah yes, I forgot how to get access to the customer attribute.  You would do it like this:

```
var methodInfo = ((MethodCallExpression)myAction.Body).Method;
var attributes = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes<T>(true);
```

**EXAMPLE**
Here is an example showing passing chained method calls to `Expression<Action>`:

```
public class ActionTest
{
    public void DoAction(Action action)
    {
        action();
    }

    public void DoExpressionAction(Expression<Action> action)
    {
        var method2Info = ((MethodCallExpression)action.Body).Method;

        // a little recursion needed here
        var method1Info = ((MethodCallExpression)((MethodCallExpression)action.Body).Object).Method;

        var myattributes2 = method2Info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), true);
        var myattributes1 = method1Info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), true);

        action.Compile().Invoke();
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    private string message;

    public MyAttribute(string message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }
}

public class MethodTest
{
    [MyAttribute("Number1")]
    public MethodTest Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Action");
        return this;
    }

    [MyAttribute("Number2")]
    public MethodTest Method2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ExpressionAction");
        return this;
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ActionTest target = new ActionTest();
        MethodTest instance = new MethodTest();

        target.DoExpressionAction(() => instance.Method1().Method2() );

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Action");
    }

    static void Method2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ExpressionAction");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to transform () => { instanceOfFooClass.Method1().Method2();} into Expression<Action> ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to transform it.  You should be able to pass it in directly with no changes.  Just let me test that.

Comment: Yup, you can pass `() => action` straight to `Expression<T>`.  You just need to add a using for `System.Linq.Expressions`

Comment: I'm getting compilation error: "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree" while trying to pass () => action as Expression<Action> argument. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I just added my sample to the answer.  Does this help?

Comment: your answer, as the next one works with void methods / calling one method at a time, but in his case, where he chains methods, im not sure it can be solved this way

Comment: @dtryon - Yup, it helped, the problem where {}. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user1439510 I see it know.  It will work if you get rid of the `{}`. like this: `Foo(() =>  instanceOfFooClass.Method1().Method2());`

Comment: I tested it with chain methods, it doesn't work properly. It seems that only last method from chain is checked for custom attributes.

Comment: @user1439510 I just posted a full example with chained methods.  Does this work for you?

Comment: @YavgenyP You can get to the chained method.  See my updated example.

Answer (score 4):

If you call your `Foo()` methdod like this:

```
Foo(instanceOfFooClass.Method);
```

Your code works as you'd expect (void methods *are* actions, after all). 
On a side note, I think "chaining" method calls in fact counts as you're only passing the last one through.

Full sample demonstrating the behavior:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute { }
    class FooClass
    {
        [MyCustom]
        public void DecoratedMethod() { Console.WriteLine("Decorated Method - executed."); }
        public void NotDecoratedMethod() { Console.WriteLine("Not Decoreated Method - executed."); }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FooClass instanceOfFooClass = new FooClass();
            Foo(instanceOfFooClass.DecoratedMethod);
            Foo(instanceOfFooClass.NotDecoratedMethod);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Foo(Action action)
        {
            if (Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(action.Method, typeof(MyCustomAttribute)).Count() == 0)
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Invalid method {0}", action.Method.Name));
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Valid method {0}", action.Method.Name));
                action.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: im not sure it will work with chained methods. in the sample he provided you somehow have to analyze the internal calls of the provided action, to check both method1 and method2. unless he rewrites his code completly, this will not work with simple checks of delegates

Comment: You're of course right, this probably wouldn't work with "chains" of methods... Honestly the whole concept feels odd to me.